# Pillow How do I create an array of images for each page compatible with .save() to a PDF?

Tags: python-imaging-library

I have been able to import a PDF with pdf2image:

```
images = convert_from_path(r"D:\Jupyter\abc.pdf", output_folder=r"D:\TempPython", poppler_path = r"D:\PopplerLIB\Library\bin")
```

Then, the main loop, in each loop, takes a page image and transforms it.
Before processing the next page I need to make a copy of the transformed page and accumulate it in an array imagesConverted compatible with:

```
images.save(pdf_path, "PDF" ,resolution=100.0, save_all=True, append_images=imagesConverted[1:])
```

But so far, I am not able to create a compatible array. I get messages such as:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'encoderinfo'
```

How do I create an array of images for each page compatible with .save() to a PDF?

Thanks

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the processed images you are accumulating are Numpy arrays, rather than `PIL Images` but you have not produced a *"minimal complete verifiable example"*.

Try code more like this:

```
imlist = []
for ...:
    # process and produce Numpy array
    imlist.append(Image.fromarray(im))

# Save list of images as PDF
imlist[0].save(pdf_path, "PDF" ,resolution=100.0, save_all=True, append_images=imlist[1:])
```